# django database models with one field common

Tags: django, database, model

I am struggling to define Django models so I can achieve following functionality as per picture below:

[image: solution required]

Basically,

I want to be able to create new projects (so, I create model: class ProjectList).

I want to assign generic list of stages for each Project so I create a model: class StageList. Stage List contains list of stages which names are always the same for each project.

Stages should contain Integer values which are the average values of the Area fields.

So, I want to create a list of Areas and I create a model: class AreaList.

AreaList may be different for every project.

The important think the end user wants to see is:

a value of Stage 1 (which is an average) for Project 1. Stage 1 is an average of for example Area 1, Area 2 in Project 1.

Stage 2 is an avg of Area 1, Area 2 in Project 2

etc.

I thought about doing a relation for AreaList as below:

```
area_num = models.ForeignKey(StageList, related_name='area_items')
```

I realized it is not a good way because it always relates to specific Stage in Stage list but I want to have few different area values for different Stages.

how I can do it ?

Comment: "I want to have few different area values for different Stages" so maybe `models.ManyToManyField('StageList')` :D ... anyway try django tutorial ... if doesn't help - try it again :D

Comment: Area will relate to many stages but I can assign one value to area only and it will be common for all stage If I do as you suggest.

Comment: I want to have one Area e.g. Area X that relates to all Stages e.g. Area X has value 1 for Stage 1, Area X has got value 2 for Stage 2, area X has value 3 for Stage 3 etc.    ... Area Z has value 1 for Stage 1, Area Z has got value 2 for Stage 2, area Z has value 3 for Stage 3 ... Stage 1 is an average of Area X and Area Z ... simple manytomany would not wrong ? correct me if I am wrong please.

Answer (score 0):

What I believe you're looking for is the following:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    pass

class Stage(models.Model):
    pass

class Area(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project)
    stage = models.ForeignKey(Stage)
    value = models.IntegerField()
```

Then to get your Stage values you'd do something like:

```
from django.db.models import Avg
project = Project.objects.get(...)
project_stages = Stage.objects.filter(
    area_set__project=project
).annotate(
    stage_value=Avg('area_set__value')
)
for project_stage in project_stages:
    print project_stage.stage_value
```